# Scope Functions in Kotlin - How do you remember what they do?

Tags: android, kotlin

Scope functions in Kotlin are clearly explained in JetBrain's  [offical documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html), including a very helpful matrix that summaries the major differences between them:

[image]

Problem is… how do you remember this? At least for me, it is (was) a struggle. So I came up with a technique that I would like to share in my own answer to this question - hope it will work for you as well. Or perhaps you can share your own ways of doing a total recall on these functions?

Comment: Hi, I do appreciate the suggestions (I struggle with these myself, and I'm not the one who downvoted you) but unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't really a good fit for this sort of opinion-based question - the question you linked has now been closed for the same reason.

Comment: @RyanM thanks, I appreciate you taking time to explain your position. Just want to clarify my take on this. The question is closed as opinion based, but in fact I was looking for practical solutions to my question - and the solution I offer is also practical, there is nothing philosophical/opinionated about it. That said, if the general consensus here is that such questions are not a good fit for this forum, so be it, no point in arguing further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One answer is mnemonics. I used it on a few occasions, not necessarily related to programming, and it never failed. So here is what I came up with for scope functions mnemonics:

**Object reference:**

> **Wrap** **this** up and send **it** to **LA**
>
> *(**w**ith, **r**un, **ap**ply - **this**);   **it** - **let, also***

**Return Value:**

[image]

**Vo**lkswagen **CC**

> Vowels (functions that start with a vowel - **a**pply, **a**lso) -  return
>   (context) object (Vo - Vowels, Object) Consonants (start with a
>   consonant - **l**et, **r**un, **w**ith) - return computation result (lambda
>   result) (CC - consonants, computation)